# pycharm jetbrains to search for text NOT in test*.py filename pattern

Tags: search, pycharm

In Pycharm, when **search for files** that **contain a given text** e.g. hitting Ctrl-Shift-F, we have the `File mask` box as in below snapshot to filter file name pattern.

I want a **NOT filter here** e.g. search for files not starting with test*.py. How can we archive this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**

Although this question is old, I'll leave the answer here just in case someone else reaches the question.

### Solution

The way to exclude results in File mask is by adding a `!` before the mask, for example: `!*test*.py`

However, this might generate an unwanted situation, because it can bring results from configuration files, or temporary files, or any file we don't want. For this, the solution is to have multiple masks at once, and this can be achieved by separating masks with `,` (comma).

### Example

If we want all files containing the word `def` in `.py` files, excluding files containing the word `tests` for any type of file, and `models` ending in `.py`, we would use the File mask: `!*test*, !*models*.py, *.py`

[image: File mask example]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you!